# Does finesse-based equipment make it easier to sneak?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Does finesse-based equipment (i.e. leather) make you harder to detect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. The only thing that has an effect on your stealth skill is... well, your stealth skill itself.

It can go from 0-10, but this value is the only thing that matters outside of Smoke Bombs (which keep you hidden for 5 seconds regardless of what armor you're wearing).

Comment: There are some unique/set finesse items that have +X to sneak, but aside from that pedantic nitpick, you are 100% correct.

Comment: Even if an armor item increases the stealth skill... *it's still increasing the stealth skill*, not providing some other bonus.

Comment: It's still *finesse-based equipment* that *makes it easier to sneak* - I've found it more likely that finesse equipment will have this type of enchantment.  Like I said, though, it's a pretty pedantic/nitpicky distinction.  In the general case, you're absolutely correct.